# LaTex. I would like to find articles on calculus written but that also are provided with the LaTex source code in order to understand it better

Tags: learning

I am new to LaTex and i would like to understand it by reading in parallel the mathematical reasoning with the source code in LaTex. Articles in Calculus for differentiable functions, limits of functions and sequences, etc.

Comment: I imagine you'll get a lot of responses to this. Fwiw I'd recommend http://spot.pcc.edu/math/clm/. Disclaimer :I used to work at PCC. Source at https://github.com/Alex-Jordan/Calculus-Lab-Manual

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Unfortunately, recommendations don't work well on .SE sites.  I don't know that I would recommend searching for a particular topic.  Instead, I would aim to start using TeX, and learn what you need as you proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [References for learning how to check for typesetting problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37379/references-for-learning-how-to-check-for-typesetting-problems)

Comment: You could browse [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/search/math?query=calculus&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50).

Comment: I'm currently reading [Kalman and Bayesian Filters in Python](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/table_of_contents.ipynb) and if you right click on the equations in the document you get a dialogue box with the top option being `Show Math As` and then choose the `TeX Commands` it opens a window with the Tex that was used to generate the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I look often into the markdown code of Wikipedia articles. You can see it by clicking on "Edit" to the right of the corresponding paragraph headline.